# Full Class Definition VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working with a large python codebase that heavily uses inheritance. I'm working in VSCode, is there some way to view a full class definition which includes all inherited methods and attributes without having to scroll up and down the class inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have you looked at the OUTLINE View, if it does not what you want write an extension that shows a View that does, or maybe somebody already did